# How to take the cube root of a negative number in VBA for Excel?

Tags: vba

I am trying to compute the cube root of a negative number in VBA for Excel.  Taking the cube root of a negative number in an Excel worksheet works fine:

```
=(-2)^(1/3)
-1.25992
```

However the same concept coded into VBA:

```
(-2)^(1/3)
```

gives a `#VALUE!`error when returning the value to the worksheet.  I suspect VBA is parsing the `1/3` to its decimal representation `0.3333...` and therefore causing a mathematical error since negative numbers can't be raised to non-integer powers in the real domain.  Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `POWER()` function:

```
POWER(-2, 1/3)
```

Comment: Works great, can't believe I missed it. Thanks! For other readers out there - POWER is not defined as a VBA function, so you have to use the `Application.WorksheetFunction.Power()` construct to access it.

Answer (score 2):

I think CarlF's/your answer is the best, but it's worth mentioning that you can use Application.Evaluate to return the result of a literal Excel formula:

```
Range("A1") =  Application.Evaluate("=(-2)^(1/3)")
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, it didn't work with `(-2)^(1/3)` as you stated.

But it worked with `-2^(1/3)`.

I have no idea why is this.

Comment: due to precedence rules, the expression evaluates as -(2^(1/3)) which circumvents the domain error of exponentiating negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If x is a positive real number then the cube root of -x is simply the negation of the cube root of x, i.e., -(x^(1/3).