# Run-time Error 5 After Successful Calculations

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I'm developing a process to automate the calculation of 3 year rolling returns based on monthly return data. Here is the part of my code that produces the error:

```
Set rolling_returns = Range([c41], [c41].End(xlDown))

start_no_begin = 6
start_no_end = 41

For Each calc In rolling_returns

reference_begin = "C" & start_no_begin
reference_end = "C" & start_no_end

    Set calculation1 = Range(reference_begin, reference_end)

     calc.Offset(0, 3) = ((WorksheetFunction.Product(calculation1)) - 1) ^ (1 / 3)
     'why is this getting stopped after a certain amount of calculations??

    start_no_begin = start_no_begin + 1
    start_no_end = start_no_end + 1

Next
```

My code runs through 175 iterations and then I get the error. I've reproduced the calculation manually and there is no error so I don't think it's a data issue. Could it be a memory issue?

Comment: Could your loop values be the issue- compared to your start and end values, step through the code until calc=174, then look at all that variable values, before hitting the step one more time.

Comment: I tried it and I still can't find where the source of the issue is. All the variables have the correct values, but it won't go any further. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: I think I've diagnosed the problem. I believe Excel VBA has a hard time calculating exponentials when the exponential is not an integer. I found this after looking specifically at the exponential problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390833/run-time-error-5-in-vba-excel-when-working-with-array

Answer (score 0):

Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911356/how-to-take-the-cube-root-of-a-negative-number-in-vba-for-excel) out - basically says you can use the `WorksheetFunction.Power` function in place of directly using an fractional exponent.

Your code doesn't mitigate the risk of trying to take the cube root of -1 because the production of `calculation1` could be zero and you deduct 1.

So your code becomes:

```
calc.Offset(0, 3) = WorksheetFunction.Power(((WorksheetFunction.Product(calculation1)) - 1), 3)
```

I'd suggest looking at what is happening as your code reaches the bottom of the data range you are processing. If you are picking up empty cells toward the end of the loop then these are normally skipped by the `WorksheetFunction.Product` function but worth checking what is happening in your specific routine.